# Errors In tmux in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tmux

**while running tmux the following errors are shown in ubuntu 18.04 :**

```
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)

  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)

Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)

  Serial number of failed request:  20

  Current serial number in output stream:  20

xrandr: cannot find output "eDP-1-1"
```

Comment: What is your question? If this is a bug report, then you should consider submitting it to the Ubuntu developpers on launchpad. I run tmux without any issue on 18.04, so your issue may be particular.

Comment: How to get rid of this errors?

Comment: Edit this question so the question becomes clear. Precisely indicate when the error occurs. In what terminal are you running tmux, does the error immediately occur after starting the program or is other action needed? It is also advised to provide system information, including whether you run on xorg or on wayland.